# Ionic - API Fetch not working on real device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, fetch-api

I'm trying to upload a .PNG file to a server. When running the application via the browser (using 'ionic serve') everything works great and the file is uploaded. But, when trying to do this on an actual android device using ('ionic cordova run android' I am getting a 400 error.

```
let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');

  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('files', filePhoto);

  let fetchAPI;

  let imageUrl;

  fetchAPI = fetch('https://api.hubapi.com/.........',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: form
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).
  then(function(json){
    test(json.objects[0].url);
    console.log(json);
    console.log(json.objects[0].name);
    console.log(json.objects[0].url);
  })
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is only working in the browser.
The error I'm recieving is:

> "POST https://api.hubapi.com/.... 400 ()"

EDIT, my config.xml

https://pastebin.com/JJNySHPV

Comment: always specify version of ionic

Comment: possible image file size may be too large, so that it throw an error 400 or 413. I suggest you please less file image or use compress the file size

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue. Now ionic framework has fixed this issue.

You just update ionic webview plugin :

First remove it:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

Then add it

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

Note : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview version should be greater than 2.x.x

For your understanding : 
fetch api not working on file scheme or protocol. you need http or https protocol to make it work.